# Python Dask Delete From Row

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I'm trying to write a script to scrub information from csvs using dask. I have a dask df created from a csv like below:

```
CUSTOMER ORDERS
  hashed_customer      firstname    lastname    email   order_id    status          timestamp
0      eater 1_uuid  1_firstname  1_lastname  1_email    12345    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 20:45:15
1      eater 2_uuid  2_firstname  2_lastname  2_email    23456    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 20:29:22
2      eater 3_uuid  3_firstname  3_lastname  3_email    34567    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 19:31:55
```

I have another csv with the hashed_customers that I need to scrub from this file. So if the hashed_customer in this file is in CUSTOMER ORDERS, I need to remove the firstname, lastname, and email from the row while keeping the rest, to look something like this:

```
CUSTOMER ORDERS
      hashed_customer      firstname    lastname    email   order_id    status          timestamp
    0      eater 1_uuid         NULL        NULL     NULL    12345    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 20:45:15
    1      eater 2_uuid  2_firstname  2_lastname  2_email    23456    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 20:29:22
    2      eater 3_uuid  3_firstname  3_lastname  3_email    34567    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 19:31:55
```

My current script looks like this:

```
print('FIND ORDERS FROM OPT-OUT CUSTOMERS')
cust_opt_out_order = []
for index, row in df_in.iterrows():
    if row.hashed_eater_uuid in cust_opt_out_id:
        cust_opt_out_order.append(row.order_id)

print('REMOVE OPT-OUT FROM OPT-IN FILE')
df_cust_out = df_in[~df_in['hashed_eater_uuid'].isin(cust_opt_out_id)]
```

But this is removing the entire row, and now I need to keep the row and only remove the name and email elements from the row. How can I drop elements from a row using pandas?

I'm trying to get a dask equivalent to pandas:

```
df_cust_out.loc[df_in['hashed_eater_uuid'].isin(cust_opt_out_id),['firstname','lastname', 'email']]=np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the Dataframe.where or Series.where methods:

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.where